# Javascript: document.url without the anchor (hash) portion

Tags: javascript, url, get, window, anchor

I've tried searching for this for 30 minutes, so I apologize if it's been asked already.

I have some Ajax which returns a set of results and when one is clicked it simply reloads the URL with the appended data to the URL for PHP to GET on the next page.  The problem is, if the user clicked to some built in anchoring (which I cannot remove), the URL will be `something.com#location1` so appending `?action=next` will turn it into `something.com#location1?action=next` which the browser interprets as a long anchor, rather than a new URL to actually direct to.

If the user never clicks the anchor portion this redirect works smoothly using `window.location=document.url+"?action=next"`

Is there a way to remove the anchor (including the hash tag) from the existing page's URL?

**SOLVED**

Using [Michael W's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15193653/713874) I was able to solve it.  I simply replaced this line:

`window.location=document.url+"?action=next"`

With this:

`window.location=document.location.href.match(/(^[^#]*)/)[0]+"?action=next"`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [None of these results help you out?](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+remove+hash+from+url)

Comment: I went with Michael W's solution (with a minor modification), marked as such and edited the original question to include the solution for future readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could match for the pre-hashtag portion of the location:

```
document.location.href.match(/(^[^#]*)/)
```

Comment: For those reading: this returns an Array.  Specifying the first element worked for me:

`window.location=document.location.href.match(/(^[^#]*)/)[0]`

I aborted using `document.url` entirely.

Answer (score 13):

This seems slightly simpler:

```
document.URL.replace(/#.*$/, "")
```

Answer (score 2):

The location object can be accessed by independent components and you can use those to reconstruct the URL with as many or as few pieces as you like.

The official documentation is offline at this time but [this site](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/location.shtml) seems to have it.

Should those be internal links you are generating, you will only need to generate a relative url and *maybe* even just `location.pathname` would suffice.

Note that you tagged your question as Javascript but since you are coding in PHP, I suspect what you need is to generate those links on the PHP side.

Comment: `location.pathname` indeed works for me. But what is its difference between `window.location.pathname`?

Comment: @JAT86 - Those are identical in that they reference the same object. It is just accessible two ways.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using:

```js
document.location.href.split('#')[0];
```

It finds the first hash and ignore the rest of the path. If there is no hash, no problem. In this case it will take the entire path.

Comment: should be considered best method imo